# Add a new XML node element to a document using webmethods

Tags: xml, integration, webmethods

I would like to create a service in `webmethods` that adds an entry to an XML file. So I converted this file to an IS document. Here is the structure of the document:

[image]

Now I want to add an entry which the user provided as input.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you should change the document "books" to a document list of type.
The best way to do this is to read the XML using one of the WmPublic XML services, add a new entry to the document list, then convert this document back to an XML string and overwrite the file from which you read it, or save it to another file. This is all possible with the existing Built-In Services.